# Eclipse c++ library not found in debug mode but found in release mode

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug a program i wrote in c++ using eclipse but i am encountering a problem when choosing the debug option.

```
/home/dupinf/workspace/HashTest/Debug/HashTest: 
/sw/st/gnu_compil/gnu/linux-rh-ws-4-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: 
version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
```

when I just run the release, it works smoothly. But when i try to go debug mode i get the error. I don't understand why it wouldn't find the library in one mode and not in the other

What shall i change in order to be able to debug and use the breakpoints ?

Comment: Is the debug version a separate install (developer version)?

Comment: the debug version is just another configuration in my eclipse. What i would like to know is what should i change in the debug config to allow it to find GLIBCXX ?

Comment: In Eclipse it is just a different configuration. In the OS it might be a separate package to install, develop version vs run-only version.

Comment: So i have to find where the GLIBCXX_3.4.15 is as a debug version ? When i find it where do i give the path to eclipse ? In the eclipse pref or my full library path ?

Comment: I mean in order to make the run work i added the location of the library in first position of my LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it seems that it isn't taken into account i in debug mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found what was the problem :

1) Go to the launch configuration for my debug
2) Go to the environment tab
3) Add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable with the path to my library
4) check the box to overwrite exist variable.

Then i can debug smoothly.

Note that even if you have modified you LD_LIBRARY_PATH in your terminal, it is not taken into account in debug mode but just in run mode.

hope it can help someone ;)

Comment: do you know if the problem is still there? I have very similar problems with Eclipse Kepler on OS-X and setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH does not help... :(

Answer (score 0):

When linking with external libraries, keep in mind that the libraries are built in either release or debug modes. When a library is built in debug mode it contains all the debugging symbols/info that a debugger hooks into to monitor the state of the application. If you are trying to build a debug version of an application and you link to the release version - this will cause a problem (as the lib you are linking with is organized differently in either the release or debug versions of the lib). The solution: rebuild the external libraries in debug mode, and link against those

Comment: I'm not really sure about this. Isnt GLIBCXX a standard library ? where can i get the source to build it in debug mode ??